# avoid to escape a special characters in javascript

Tags: javascript, escaping, special-characters

My server returns value as `support\testing`. When I get this value in client it can be escaped as `support     testing`. `\t` is escaped as tab space.

How do I avoid escaping special characters in JavaScript?

Comment: Return `"support\\testing"`? See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/2yfce773(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: you should escape server side and then send to javascrippt

Comment: you could avoid using backslash instead of slash.

Comment: I'm confused.  Do you want to avoid un-escaping by changing the server, or un-escape on the client?

Comment: what language is your server using to output the value? You should use proper json encoding when outputting JS data.

Comment: If `\t` is rendered as tab, should not you get `support<tab>esting`?

Comment: is there any way to un escape in javascript itself, if server gives \t and i stored that into javascript variable, it has escaped as tab space. my requirement is to avoid this operation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your server needs to output the string with proper escaping.

In this case, you want a backslash character in the output; backslash is a special character, so that should be escaped.

The escape sequence for a backslash is `\\` (ie two backslashes), but you shouldn't need to think about specific escape codes -- if you're outputting JS data, you should be outputting it using proper escaping for the whole string, which generally means you should be using JSON encoding.

Most server languages these days provide JSON encoding as a built-in feature. You haven't specified which language your server is using, but for example if it's written in PHP, you would output your string as `json_encode($string)` rather than just outputting `$string` directly. Other languages provide a similar feature. This will protect you not just from broken backslash characters, but also from other errors, such as quote marks or line feeds in your strings, which will also cause errors if you put them into a Javascript code as an unescaped string.

Comment: Given it's a web page, there is probably more contexts in the context stack that need to be escaped for. If it's string output inside script element then you need to watch out for `</script>` because simply escaping for javascript strings in general doesn't do anything about that :9

Answer (score 8):

You can use tagged template literals

```
var str = (s => s.raw)`support\testing`[0]
```

The anonymous arrow function will serve as tag and `s.raw` contains the original input

Comment: thank you from php land, I have no idea wth am I looking at but you saved me.

Answer (score 3):

If you are able to change the server-side code, you should add the escape character there: `"support\\testing"`.

That will result in the desired result.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @kiamlaluno it may seem like a comment but is also a legit answer that will return what the op wants.

Comment: In that case, you should expand it. What you wrote has been already said in a comment; the user chose to write a comment for a good reason. I would change it to a statement, as you seem to actually asking a question to the OP, rather than answering him.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple replace:

```
str.replace("\t","\\t");
```

And do this for other characters you need replacing.

Comment: or better: `str.replace(/\t/g, '\\t');`

Comment: This will also change intentional tabs, it just trades one problem for another

Answer (score -2):

Best Solution for this

```
function valid(f) {            
        debugger;
        var s = "!@#$%^&*()+=-[]\\\';,./{}|\":<>?~";
        str = f.value;
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
           if (s.indexOf(str.charAt(i)) != -1) {
              //alert("The box has special characters. \nThese are not allowed.\n");
              f.value = f.value.replace(str.charAt(i), '');// : null;
              return false;
            }
        }
 }
```