# TinyButStrong error single quote within a string

Tags: javascript, tinybutstrong

I have a problem with single quote (`'`):

```
<button type="button" class="tasto btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" 
                        onclick="myFunction('[blkfeatured.lastname]')">
```

If `lastname = "Mario Rossi"`, this works, but
If `lastname = "Stefano d'Orazio"`, it doesn't work, because I've created another `'`, and then
I have syntax error.

Look this example (please copy and try it):

```
<button type="button" onclick="nominativo = 'Mario Rossi'; myFunction(nominativo)">
    <span>Vedi informazioni</span>
</button>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    function myFunction(nominativo) {
        alert(nominativo);
        iframe.src = 'nomesito.php?nome=' + nominativo;
    }
</script>
```

Now... if you try this program WORK, but if you change lastname:
"nominativo = 'Stefano d'Orazio'  don't work.

Can you help me?

Comment: Ever heard of Escape Chars ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - How to show escape characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21672334/javascript-how-to-show-escape-characters-in-a-string)

Comment: Look here for characters that need escaping in Javascript https://stackoverflow.com/a/21672439/5411817

And here to see an example regex that you may modify for your needs:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17552048/5411817

Answer (score 0):

In a TBS tag, use parameter `strconv=js` in order to escape a Javascript string.

```
<button ... onclick="myFunction('[blkfeatured.lastname;strconv=js]')" />
```

For more details, see the [doc](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#html_field_prm_strconv)