# Regex character removed from HTML element's attribute's value upon appending to DOM

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a function that does some text validation logic on inputs before saving their values. Part of that validation is to test the values against a RegExp pattern for a match. The RegExp pattern for each element is taken from a custom attribute on the element.

Example:  `<input type="email" ... validationregexp="\@\w+\.\w+">`

This works perfectly fine for elements which are statically written in the HTML files.
However, if I dynamically create and append the element via JavaScript some of the characters are removed from the `validationregexp=...` attributes value

example:

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.className = "my-input";
input.setAttribute("type", "email");
input.setAttribute("validationRegexp", "\@\w+\.\w+");
container.append(input);
```

inspected element in dev tool then gives me this:

`<input class="my-input" type= "email" validationregexp="@w+.w+">`

resulting in errors of RegExp validation. Why would the attribute value be changed from what I declare it to be to something different?

Comment: `"\\@\\w+\\.\\w+"`

Comment: As to the why: \ is an escape character. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17551867/avoid-to-escape-a-special-characters-in-javascript

Comment: Excellent, why does it differ between writing it in HTML vs JS. I guess this is because JS parses it as Regex whereas HTML cannot and thus leaves it as is ?>

Comment: A small smartass hint: HTML5 input elements can have the pattern attribute, which will be executed automatically on submit. The browser does the job for you.

Comment: Yes, I previously suggested implementing this to the employer. Wants to keep this functionality in JS. Obsessed with everything being written in JS rather in HTML zzz