# Using path.dirname to find path

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, path

Below is the simple code which I wrote to find the directory of a file

```
const path = require('path');   

console.log("The full loction is :-  " , __filename);          // Line 1
console.log("The path is :- "  , path.dirname(__filename));             // Line 2

console.log(path.dirname('d:\NODEJS\FreeCodeCamp\tempCodeRunnerFile.js'));     // Line 3 :- same value as
```

The output are as follow

```
The full loction is :-   d:\NODEJS\FreeCodeCamp\tempCodeRunnerFile.js
The path is :-  d:\NODEJS\FreeCodeCamp
d:
```

[The output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6grmT.png)

Now ,  in `Line 3` , I have put same value as `__filename`  as it was in `Line 2` but only in string form .Then why the output of `path.dirname` is different in `Line 2` and `Line 3`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the node.js path documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#windows-vs-posix) it depends on operating system as to how the path is read.

For Windows, it would expect your path to be written like this:

```
d:\\NODEJS\\FreeCodeCamp\\tempCodeRunnerFile.js
```

That is (also) because of the way strings work: when you use a `\` you're signaling that you're [escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17551867/avoid-to-escape-a-special-characters-in-javascript) whatever comes after the backslash, so for example `\t` would be a [tab] character or `\n` a [newline]. So the string you're giving to the path method sees `d:[newline]odejs[somecharacter]reeCodeCamp[tab]empCodeRunnerFile.js`, which it then interprets as a weirdly named file located directly in `d:`, thus the output is correct as only `d:`.

So to write an actual `\` into your string, you need to escape the backslash itself, resulting in `\\`.